# std::ostream printing address at end of function

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
std::vector<double>residuals;
std::cout << Print_res(std::cout);
std::ostream& Print_res(std::ostream& os) const {

  os << "\tresidual" << std::endl;
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 22 ; i++) {
    os << "\t\t" << residuals[i] << std::endl;
  }
  os << std::flush;
  return os;
};
```

It prints the residuals correctly, but at the end of the output tags an address as follows:

```
2275
2279.08
2224.0835
0x80c5604
```

how do I fix this?
EDIT: after reading everyone's comments I replaced the call to the function `Print_res` with a `std::copy` as

```
 std::copy(residuals.begin(), residuals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout,"\n"));
```

and that did not print the address, so I presume there is something wrong in the way I have written the function.

Comment: Its printing the address of `std::flush`

Comment: Please post a _complete_ test case. `residuals` isn't even declared in your example.

Comment: You need to do `os.flush()` instead()

Comment: Works fine for me. It flushes the stream, but no address is printed. What platform are you on?

Comment: @NeelBasu: Can you explain why it is doing this rather than causing `flush` to be called on `os`?

Comment: @NeelBasu: `os << std::flush` is just fine. The problem is somewhere else. Also, guesswork should never be a solution, without knowing the *cause* of the problem.

Comment: `std::endl` already performs a flush. So either remove the explicit `std::flush` or use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`. This won't solve your problem, but it's good to know anyway.

Comment: @CharlesBailey,residuals is just a vector of doubles

Comment: @Sjoerd, removing the `std::flush` did not solve the problem, it still prints the address

Comment: @user1155299: Please post a _complete_ test case. Evidently something is printing an address after this function is called but we can only guess what it is without seeing the complete code.

Comment: Hmm I see. I think You need to show more code e.g. where `residuals` is declared

Comment: That `const` doesn't look legal. Only member functions can be declared `const`.

Comment: Try `residuals.at(i)` instead.

Comment: Please show how `Print_res()` is invoked - it looks like that's where the problem is occurring (at or after the call site).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I just updated my post with that statement

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thanks, that was indeed the cause of the problem

Comment: @Nawaz, if you don't mind, I'd like to get in contact with you. how can I reach you

Comment: @user1155299: My email-address is : `sir_nawaz959@yahoo.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::cout << Print_res(std::cout);
```

This is not legal at global scope so the code that you have posted is not valid. If this statement were executed from, say, a function then `Print_res` would be called and then the return value of `Print_res` would also be streamed to `std::cout`. This is most likely not what you meant. You probably want just this:

```
Print_res(std::cout);
```

Your statement performs the equivalent of:

```
std::cout << std::cout;
```

In C++03 (which you must be using), `std::cout` has an `operator void*` (from `std::basic_ios<char>`) the result of which is what is being printed.

Comment: understood. that was indeed the problem. thanks a bunch for the explanation :-)